# How to speed up pandas apply lambda function for numba engine

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, numba

For the case speeding up pandas I learnt about numba engine and can speedup significantly.

In latest case, I like to get arbitrary index using argsort with lambda, but it seems quite slow. Why lambda slows down code? How can I write proper apply function to not compromise speed further??, I even wrap the lambda function in nb.njit but still cant see more speedup.

Logically speaking np.argmax and np.argsort [-1] are same, but np.argsort can be used to get median for example. So I did like to confirm if there is better way to write `lambda x: np.argsort(x)[5]` for example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import timeit
import sys


def f1():
    a = pd.DataFrame(range(10000000))
    return a.rolling(10).apply(np.argmax, engine='numba', raw=True)

nb.njit((nb.int64)(nb.float64[:]))
def f(x):
    return np.argsort(x)[5]

def f2():
    a = pd.DataFrame(range(10000000))
    return a.rolling(10).apply(f, engine='numba', raw=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: f2(), number=10) / 10)
```

```
(base) xxx:~$ python test.py f1
1.4400632409029641
(base) xxx:~$ python test.py f2
5.061740894208197
```

Comment: I've only seen numba used with a decorator, but I recall that since it's JIT compiled, the first execution is slow and subsequent executions are fast. Did you try using `timeit`?

Comment: Literally no change, in apply the function has to be applied again 10000000 - 1 times, so timeit should not do anything significant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were my results using `timeit`

```py
In [1]: %timeit a.rolling(10).apply(np.argmax, engine='numba', raw=True)
16.9 ms ± 477 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [2]: %timeit a.rolling(10).apply(np.argmax, raw=True)
176 ms ± 3.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit a.rolling(10).apply(l1, engine='numba', raw=True)
79.8 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit a.rolling(10).apply(l1, raw=True)
116 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Note that I did this with `a = pd.DataFrame(range(100_000))`.

Comment: It does not change anything, I updated with timeit. For 10000000 function will be applied 10000000 - 1 times more after compilation

Comment: My results show that setting the engine to numba is faster.

Comment: Yes it is. But question is `np.argmax` and `lambda x: np.argsort(x)[-1]` are logically equivalent but why using numba enigine `lambda x: np.argsort(x)[-1]` takes 79.8 ms and `np.argmax`  16.9 ms. Why so?? I need to write lambda in such a way that both are almost similar

Comment: I want to confirm what ever I have written is it best possible??

Comment: I hope I'm not misunderstanding, but even though `np.argsort(x)[-1]` has the same result as `np.argmax`, the semantics are different: argsort requires sorting and is O(nlogn), even if you only want information that could have been accessed in O(n), which is what `np.argmax` is doing.